# I want regular expression remove brackets in PostgreSQL version 9.3.5

Tags: php, postgresql

I want regular expression that's remove to brackets in PostgreSQL version 9.3.5

example

```
3136.27(0.31A.G)
```

output is    3136.27

and i am using for following regular expression but it's not working postgesql version 9.3.5

SELECT regexp_replace('3136.27(0.31A.G)', '/(([^)]+))(\s*-)/', '$1$2')

Comment: And what have you tried in order to get the desired result?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('3136.27(0.31A.G)', '\(.*\)', '');

┌────────────────┐
│ regexp_replace │
├────────────────┤
│ 3136.27        │
└────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you if you want your output to be 3136.27:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('3136.27(0.31A.G)', '/(([^()]+))(\(.*\))/', '$1')
```